# Can not push the data into array using Python

Tags: python, arrays, django

I am trying to push data into array using Python but getting the following error.

```
root[].append({'lname':lname,'roomname':roomname,'seat':seat,'project':project,'video':video})
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Here is my code:

```
def viewbook(request):
    doc = minidom.parse("roomlist.xml")
    staffs = doc.getElementsByTagName("location")
    for staff in staffs:
        lname=staff.getAttribute("name");
        roomname=staff.getElementsByTagName("roomname")[0]
        seat=staff.getElementsByTagName("noseats")[0]
        project=staff.getElementsByTagName("projectorscreen")[0]
        video=staff.getElementsByTagName("videoconf")[0]
        root[].append({'lname':lname,'roomname':roomname,'seat':seat,'project':project,'video':video})
    return render(request,'booking/viewbook.html',{'people': root})
```

Here I need to push the set of data into one array.

Comment: `root[].append(...)`? What is `root[]`?

Comment: How did you get on with the help rendered below, satya? It is not strictly mandatory to accept/vote/reply answers, but I'm hoping you've just forgotten.

Answer (score 1):

Well, like the error says, that's not valid syntax.

Firstly you need to define the list - outside of the loop. Then, when you want to append to it, you just reference it; you don't use those square brackets.

```
root = []
for staff in staffs:
    ...
    root.append(...)
```